# How to create a sub Post/page in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to create sub posts on posts on my site. My post url will be

```
site.com/post-title
```

I want my sub posts like this.

```
site.com/post-title/subpost1 

site.com/post-title/subpost2 

site.com/post-title/subpost3
```

How can I do that? Is there a plugin that can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wordpress: how to add hierarchy to posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750931/wordpress-how-to-add-hierarchy-to-posts)

Answer (score 0):

With posts, to the best of my knowledge, this cannot be done.  However, it can be done very easily with pages:

1. Create the first page (page-title)
2. Create the second page (subpage1)

On the right-hand side, you should see a box called "Page Attributes".  There is a section called "Parent".  Choose "post-title" from there, and voilà.  The page structure and everything should follow.  Repeat for as many sub-pages as you wish.

By the way, the technical term for this in WordPress is called "hierarchy", and you can find a lot more information by searching for that term.  [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Organizing_Your_Pages) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It can not possible with post or subposts like site.com/post-title/subpost1 
Create category and then assign post to category then your url will be

```
site.com/post-category/post1
site.com/post-category/post2
```